# How can I implement domino data services within an xpinc application to display a notes view in a restful state

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpinc

I have an xPages application that I would like to get working in the Notes client via xpinc. I have a view that displays its information via domino data services as json. How can I make this available to my xpinc application?

Comment: Yes.  More details would be helpful.  In particular, what do you mean by "domino data services"?  Are you using the XPages REST service control or the full [Domino data service](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Domino_Data_Service_reference_dds10&content=apicontent)?

Comment: I am using the full domino data service. I suspect that the service is not going to be available to the client, while the xPages REST service would be available to xpinc with the correct URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Patrick.  You answered your own question in the comments section.

The full Domino data service does not run locally on the Notes client.  Therefore, your xpinc application can't use a local instance of the data service.  On the other hand, the XPages REST service control should work locally.  The REST service control uses some of the same underlying code as the data service, so you should be able to make it return essentially the same JSON representation of view entries.  It may take a bit more work, but it's the best option for xpinc.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that. I moved over to the xpages REST service. I wonder if there is a way to performance test the two.